# Geoserver ExternalGraphic draw icon incorrect

Tags: geoserver

I run into a problem with Geoserver.

I'm drawing multiple icons which each represent a place all over my map using [ExternalGraphic](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/pointsymbols.html).
But geoserver didn't draw them correctly as they are. I attach an image as the result of geoserver drawing:

[image: Image example of error]

As you can see, the 2 car icon, both got cut off around 1 pixel comapre to its original size (1 got cut off from top down while another from bottom up). It make same icon look differentfrom place to place. And i think because of this cutting, after lose some pixel, they resize the image back to its original size, which make the $ on top left look blurry compare to the one next to it.

Also as in [External graphic document](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/pointsymbols.html) mention, i didn't use any Size attribute so they won't get resize or anything. So i'm not sure why the image got cut off like that.

Any1 can help me about this case ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you open a report at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS attaching one of the images and your style document.

Comment: I saw one report with same problem over there since 2011 but still in open state. So want to ask here if any1 ever got the same problem before.

Comment: I marked this as accpted answer since Andrea Aime give me an answer overthere at jira. The problem will be fix in Geoserver ver 2.5.x which beta will be release in more than 1 week from now. Just so for any1 who got the same problem as me.